# Laravel casts set date format not working

Tags: laravel

faced such a problem. There is a Booking model. Booking has fields time_from and time_to. When I call some kind of Booking want so that the format is different. Tried using $casts = ['time_from' => 'datetime:m-d-Y']; not working! What could be the problem???

Model

```
class Booking extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $casts = [
        'time_from' => 'datetime:m-d-Y',
        'time_to' =>  'datetime:m-d-Y'
    ];
    protected $dateFormat = 'm-d-y';
    protected $fillable = [
        'room_id',
        'time_from',
        'time_to',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'special_requirements',
        'when_wait_you',
    ];

    public function room(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Room::class);
    }
}
```

Migration

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('bookings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('room_id');
            $table->dateTime('time_from');
            $table->dateTime('time_to');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->text('special_requirements')->nullable();
            $table->string('when_wait_you')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Result

[image]

Comment: what "is not working"?.....

Comment: time_from and time_to format not m-d-Y. Casts not working

Comment: okay, where are you serializing the model? otherwise there is no way for you to confirm if it is "working" or not

Comment: i get by controller first Booking but attributes time_from and time_to not work casts format.

Comment: how do you know they are "not working"? have you serialized the model?

Comment: $booking = App\Models\Booking::first();
       dd($booking);

Comment: that is not serializing the model ...

Comment: What are you saying ? I already let you know through the caste that the format needs to be changed, go to the laravel documentation.

Comment: "When defining a date or datetime cast, you may also specify the date's format. This format will be used when the model is **serialized to an array or JSON**"   ... so again, where are you serializing the model?

Comment: Laravel Documentaction.



Customizing The Date Format Per Attribute
You may customize the serialization format of individual Eloquent date attributes by specifying the date format in the model's cast declarations:


protected $casts = [
    'birthday' => 'date:Y-m-d',
    'joined_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:00',
];

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#date-serialization

Comment: last time ... where in your code are you **serializing** (to array or JSON) the model instance?

Comment: what me need json or array??? im not underestand you. im just call booking with id.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63549737/4575350

Comment: you have to serialize the model ...   "This format will be used when the model is **serialized** to an array or JSON" ...  the formatting is used **WHEN** the model is **serialized**

Comment: is anyone know $dates in laravel 7.x gone where? I mean I think he want to use $dates using casts,because now $dates not working anymore on eloquent model like before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The casting is done when you convert the model to an array or json format.

```
class Booking extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $casts = [
        'time_from' => 'datetime:m-d-Y',
    ];
}
```

```
App\Models\Booking::first()->time_from

=> Illuminate\Support\Carbon { ... }
```

```
App\Models\Booking::first()->toArray()['time_from'] 

=> '01-02-2021'
```

```
App\Models\Booking::first()->toJson()

=> "{... "time_from":"01-02-2021", ....}"
```

Comment: Anyway on my laravel 8.x it doesn't even change the time_from to carbon, is there anything wrong with my project, I mean I did the same way as yours, just different column. I tried `dd($data->time_from)` and it return string, not date, but it work on tinker as date but only when direct using `Models::find($id)->time_from`

Comment: Thank you! I understand me error. I forgot serializing me data. toArray or ToJson()

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. Serialization is happening via JsonResource. Using Laravel 8.

If I manually access to model and convert it to array via toArray() it works as expected (I get the formatted date). But it doesn't happen using JsonResource collection: MyJsonResource::collection($query->get())

I can't believe nobody has noticed this.

Comment: @John Smith I think this is working as  intended. `$casts` is for serializacion (`toArray` or `toJson`). Api Resources are different. You're supposed to be explicit about what they return.

Comment: Can you please give me an example how can I benefit from this? Why should I need to convert to array in order to use castable data? Most of the time I interect with the actual model instance properties, in that case, I need to use accesors to convert each property?

Comment: You can get the formatted value by using Carbon's `format` method. `{{ $model->time_from->format('m-d-Y'); }}`. You might need to use the Carbon instance for other things, like obtaining date differences.